# Bash kdialog Input Box Not Clossing? Possible bad return from msgbox

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I am coding in bash ,using Ubuntu 18.04,  and I am playing around with kdialog. I made a simple magic eight ball themed program and I am unable to close the input box and exit the program, instead I get stuck in a loop. This code was originally made in BASH dialog and I decided to change it to kdialog. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It is something simple that I am overlooking.

```
#!/bin/bash
#version 3

OUTPUT="TEMP.txt"
>$OUTPUT

while [ true ]
do

shuffle() {
   local i tmp size max rand
   size=${#array[*]}
   max=$(( 32768 / size * size ))

   for ((i=size-1; i>0; i--)); 
    do
      while (( (rand=$RANDOM) >= max )); 
    do :; 
    done
      rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))
      tmp=${array[i]} 
      array[i]=${array[rand]} 
      array[rand]=$tmp
   done
}

array=( 'It Is Certain' 
'Without A Doubt' 
'Maybe' 
'Signs Point To Yes' 
'Most Likely'
'As I See It, Yes'
'Ask Again Later'
'Concentrate And Ask Again'
'HAHAH No..'
'Ask Again'
'Have Faith In Yourself'
'Very Doubtful'
'Outlook Not So Good'
'My Sources Say No'
'Unknown At This Time' 
'Could Happen Any Moment Now'
'Is That A Joke?'
'Unlikely' )

shuffle

function sayhello(){
    local n=${array[@]}-""
    #display it 
kdialog --msgbox "This Is What I See:  ${array}"
 #--clear --msgbox "${array}" 8 41
}



# show an inputbox
kdialog --title "Welcome " \
--inputbox "Ask and you shall recieve great fortune: " #8 60 

function think_tank(){
progress=$(kdialog --progressbar "hmmm Let Me Think..." 4);
sleep 1;
qdbus $progress Set "" value 1 > /dev/null;
sleep 1;
qdbus $progress Set "" value 2 > /dev/null;
sleep 1;
qdbus $progress Set "" value 3 > /dev/null;
sleep 1;
qdbus $progress Set "" value 4 > /dev/null;
sleep 1;
qdbus $progress close > /dev/null;
sleep 1
#kdialog --title "This is a passive popup" --passivepopup \
#"It will disappear in about 10 seconds" 10

}
# get response
response=$? 

# get data stored in $OUPUT using input redirection
name=$(<$OUTPUT)

case $response in
  0) 
    think_tank
    sayhello ${array[@]}
    ;;
   1) 
    echo "Goodbye For Now." 
exit 0
;;  
  255) 
   echo "Goodbye For Now."
exit 0
;;
esac

#rm $OUTPUT
done
done
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleep I easily figured this issue out. I removed the case statement and used if statements instead. The program would not break out of the case statement due to a return 0 from kdialog's --msgbox.

```
#made some quick msgbox functions 
    if [ "$?" = 0 ]; 
    then
        think_tank #progress bar
        msg_box #results
    elif [ "$?" = 1 ]; 
    then
        goodbye #closing message box
    exit 0;
    else
        error #error message box
    exit 0;
    fi;
```

Comment: This doesn't particularly make sense. You seem to be examining the `$?` from a different program than you intend.

Comment: It is working like it should for what I wanted. For this case it doesn't matter what the inputs are by the user and the '$?' is just keeping track of the msgbox statuses. Closing the box or exiting out returns a 1.

Comment: Yes, but after the first `if`, the value in `$?` corresponds to the value of the command after the `if`.  Try it: `sh -c 'exit 2'; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then   echo success; elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then echo one; else echo $?; fi` prints
`one`

Comment: I see what your saying and please correct me if I am wrong, I found through the --man page that the --msgbox returns a 0 value. That is how I stay in my loop until I want to close the program. It loops through each box and closes properly now, there is a while loop that encompasses the entire code. I can post the finished code if you'd like.

Comment: All I'm trying to say is that replacing the `case` statement was not an improvement, and that one of the code paths here will never execute, and thus can be removed if you don't regard that as a bug.

Comment: If you want a catch-all in `case` like the final `else` here, that's `*) exit 0;;`

Comment: tripleee you are are right, the last else statement is useless. I just wanted to get my boxes to close properly without getting stuck in a loop. That has been accomplished so I will go back and clean it up sometime. Thanks for all the comments.